# One user is not able to connect LDAP server from our application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ldap

I have an application built in ASP.Net 3.0 and upgraded to 4.7 .Net Framework and deployed on a web server.
In the Login page of the application I am validating user credential through LDAP via WebAPI.

Everyone is able to login to the application but authentication to the LDAP is getting failed only for one user. That user is able to connect to LDAP via other applications. He is able to access those applications which are also authenticating him via same LDAP Domain.

When we checked this with AD team they are not able to find any log for that user, so suspect LDAP server itself is not getting hit for that user.

We are using below code to connect to LDAP server.

```
 public static bool IsActiveDirectoryLoginValid(string username, string password, out string errorMessage)
    {
        bool authenticated = false;
        string _activeDirectoryDomain = "domain controller name";

        try
        {
            directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", _activeDirectoryDomain), username, password);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
            ds.FindOne();

            authenticated = directoryEntry.NativeObject != null;
            errorMessage = !authenticated ? "Unable to authenticate user with provided username and password!" : null;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationHelper : IsActiveDirectoryLoginValid " + username, ex);
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            authenticated = false; // most commonly user name/ password incorrect
        }

        return authenticated;
    }
```

Comment: Is it catching an exception or not finding a NativeObject?

Comment: Anyway - your code does not just authenticate the user. It also checks if the user is authorized to read active directory information. You should limit yourself to authentication. Just don't check NativeObject. If it has managed to do the search - the password is valid (otherwise it will throw an exception).

Comment: Hi Fredrik, Thanks for looking into this. Agree with you but only for one user  NativeObject was throwing the exception so I found the search code on internet and thinking to use this. I will remove the NativeObject and will re-deploy the code tomorrow. I will let you know the outcome. just 1 query - AD team is not able to find any failure log of the user in the server so I suspect user is not able to connect the LDAP server itself. If I remove the NativeObject code will it will able to connect the LDAP server though to the user?

Comment: There is no failure from the AD point of view, assuming that my analysis is correct of course. It is behaving as intended for the operation you are attempting.

Comment: Yes, just doing a FindOne will cause it to connect to the LDAP with the supplied credentials.

Comment: Hi Fedrik, I removed the NativeObject but unable to search. FindOne() method is getting failed. Exception:ExtendedErrorMessage:8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0905A6, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839ErrorCode:-2147023570Message:The user name or password is incorrect.
Data:System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal : 
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): The user name or password is incorrect.

Comment: Error message is pretty clear on what it thinks.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, Password was getting truncated which sending from MVC to WebAPI if it was having '#' symbol in the password. We corrected it and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password was getting truncated which sending from MVC to WebAPI if it was having '#' symbol in the password. We corrected it and issue got resolved.

Also, As Fredrik suggested NativeObject is checks if the user is authorized to read active directory information. I removed the NativeObject and used FindOne() method to search.